# When to use 'Ich bin', 'es geht mir', 'Ich habe' and 'mir ist'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

If you wanted to translate "*I'm hot*" into German, like "*I'm burning up cause it's hot outside*", it would translate to "*Ich bin heiß*" which has a bad connotation. So it is translated to "*Mir ist heiß*".

If you wanted to say "I'm in a good mood" you wouldn't say "Ich bin gute Laune" instead you would say "Ich habe gute Laune".

In which cases do you use each one?

Comment: "I'm hot" would be translated to "Ich habe heiss".
"Ich bin heiss", or "Sie/Er ist heiss" have nothing to do with temperate, but rather with the look of a person.
"Es geht mir heiss" would be wrong as well :)

Comment: Would it be mir ist heiss?

Comment: "Ich bin heiß" exists too. It means "I'm hot" with the meaning of of sexually desirable.

Comment: @John: You can't say "Ich bin gute Laune" because that would mean that you are the good mood, but "Ich bin guter Laune".

Comment: @Lukas: Heiß sein hat nicht nichts, sondern ausschließlich mit Temperatur zu tun. Bei körperlicher Erregung weiten sich die Blutgefäße, das Herz schlägt schneller (das sagt man nicht nur so - das tut es wirklich), die Haut wird rot (auch das ist keine Metapher), und es wird einem wirklich heiß. Neben eigener Anschauung, die besser überzeugt als alles andere, kann ich noch Masters & Johnson, "Die sexuelle Reaktion" empfehlen.

Comment: @john "Mir ist heiss" is correct

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt, es hat in dem Sinne mit der Temparatur zu tun.

Comment: @user: Na ja, wenn man(n) sagt "die ist echt heiß", dann geht es aber nicht um die Temperatur der Frau, sondern um die des Sprechers. (Bei "ihr ist heiß" würde es um die der Frau gehen.)

Comment: Der Vollständigkeit halber: Die Bedeutung "begehrenswert" hat "heiß" in der Regel, wenn es nicht auf den Sprecher selbst bezogen ist. Im letzteren Fall geht es meistens darum, dass der Sprecher jemanden/etwas begehrenswert findet (+ Präposition "auf"), also synonym zu "scharf sein": "Ich bin scharf/heiß auf Eis" - oder eben "heiß auf Susi", vermutlich "weil sie so heiß ist".

Comment: Da Beziehungen ein wechselseitiger Prozess sind wirkt eine Frau, die selbst heiß ist, eher heiß auf Männer, als eine Frau die im Momement anderes im Sinn hat. Insofern ist eine enge Verbindung von heiß sein und heiß wirken natürlich gegeben. Eine wenig feinsinnige Sprache kann sich aber davon, ob die Frau nun wirklich heiß ist lösen, und gerade wo nur Phantasien eine Rolle spielen wird dann von einer Person als heiß gesprochen, die im Moment alles andere ist als heiß, von der die Vorstellung aber gerne phantasiert, dass sie es wäre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use **Ich bin** if you want to describe a condition or state using the adjective or a substantive preceded by an adjective and the word "in":

> Ich bin gelangweilt. <sub>I am bored.</sub>
>
> Ich bin hungrig. <sub>I am hungry.</sub>
>
> Ich bin in guter Laune. <sub>I am in a good mood.</sub>
>
> Ich bin in guter Verfassung. <sub>I am in a good condition.</sub>

And if *you* are burning then you can say:

> Ich bin heiß. <sub>I am hot.</sub>

Otherwise this has just a figurative meaning of being sexually attractive, thus you can say about a gorgeous woman:

> Sie ist heiß. <sub>She's hot.</sub>

---

You use **Mir ist** to describe a feeling using an adjective

> Mir ist langweilig. <sub>I am bored.</sub>
>
> Mir ist schwindelig. <sub>I feel dizzy.</sub>
>
> Mir ist kalt. <sub>I feel cold.</sub>

Most times when you would use *I feel* in English you can translate it with *Mir ist* into German.

---

You use **Ich habe** to describe a feeling, using the substantive (which again can be preceded by an adjective)

> Ich habe schlechte Laune. <sub>I am in a bad mood.</sub>
>
> Ich habe Hunger. <sub>I am hungry.</sub>
>
> Ich habe Fieber. <sub>I have fever.</sub>

---

You use **es geht mir** only to describe how things are going. In essence, there are just three situations: A good, a bad and neutral one.

> Es geht mir gut. <sub>I am fine.</sub>
>
> Es geht mir schlecht. <sub>I am awful.</sub>
>
> Es geht so. <sub>I am so-so.</sub>

Comment: Side note: I only refer to the usages regarding your feelings and condition. Of course there are more usages of "Ich bin" and "Ich habe" like: "Ich bin Pilot." or "Ich habe gewonnen.", but they are off-topic for this question.

Answer (score 6):

"Es geht mir heiß" is wrong. You'd say "mir ist heiß" instead (see also [this thread](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4701/1684)).

You say **"ich habe"** (not: "have") if followed by a noun describing your mood. For example, "gute Laune" is a (qualified) noun, therefore you say "ich habe gute Laune". "Ich bin gute Laune" would mean that you *are* the mood, which is obviously wrong. However, in this case you could say "ich bin gute*r* Laune" instead.

**"Es geht mir"** is exclusively used with words in the "good/bad" scale, e.g. "es geht mir gut", "es geht mir schlecht", "es geht mir mittelmäßig", "es geht mir prima", etc.

For adjectives you'd use either **"ich bin"** or **"mir ist"**, but I don't know a good rule when to use which. Note that there's also "mir ist schlecht" which has a slightly different meaning than "Es geht mir schlecht". "Es geht mir schlecht" means you don't feel well, while "mir ist schlecht" means you feel like vomiting.

Here are a few cases:

- Ich bin hungrig – I'm hungry
- Ich bin durstig – I'm thirsty
- Ich bin müde – I'm tired
- Ich bin wütend – I'm angry
- Mir ist warm – I'm hot
- Mir ist schwindlig – I'm dizzy
- Mir ist langweilig – I'm bored