# Why do you ask "ist dir kalt" but "bist du krank"?

Tags: dative, question

When you are asking someone whether they are cold, you ask "ist dir kalt" instead of "bist du kalt", as you might expect. I understand this is because the question is dative.

However, when you ask whether someone is sick, you would say "bist du krank". In this case, it is not dative.

Why is this the case? Why is it that some questions of this nature of dative and some are not, and how do you know when to use which case?

Comment: Related questions are [When to use 'Ich bin', 'es geht mir', 'Ich habe' and 'mir ist'?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4731/when-to-use-ich-bin-es-geht-mir-ich-habe-and-mir-ist) and [Is “Mir ist kalt” correct? Did I hear it correctly?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/is-mir-ist-kalt-correct-did-i-hear-it-correctly).

Comment: What do you mean by "why"?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I mean, by what ruleset is this applied? E.g., in the case of "folgen", it's because it's a dative verb. Could it be that kalt is a "dative adjective", so to speak?

Comment: Not everything living languages do can be traced back to rules. Some things, especially expressions, are as they are without too much strucural reason behind them. They have developed historically.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann that would also be a sufficient "why".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann the development isn't fossilized. One can well try to give a synchronic explanation of the understood difference, which tends to change very slowly because it's contracted at a young age, like a common cold. I'd argue the difference is intrinsic vs extrinsic properties: sickness, fear, clarity etc come from inside, naively speaking; these are basic feelings; perhaps the concepts are learned before a development stage can reflect the environment, long before the words. Cold obviously surrounds us, and only ... wait, I mixed something up. cp *mir ist übel*, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bist Du kalt?" and "Ist Dir kalt?" are both valid questions, but ask for different things. For simplicity's sake, I'll go back to the declarative sentences.

"Du bist kalt" refers to the physical quality of the person's body. I can grab somebody's hands and say, "Oh, Du bist aber kalt". It can also be used figuratively, to convey that somebody is emotionally cold.

"Dir ist kalt" refers to the person *feeling* cold, that the person's freezing. That'll often coincide with the person's body being physically cold, but it doesn't necessarily have to.

In English, both variants are expressed as "You are cold".

So basically, the analogous question to "Bist Du krank?" wouldn't be "Ist Dir kalt?", but "Bist Du kalt?", with the difference in meaning as I explained.

Comment: @Arsak Fair enough, I've added a sentence about that.

Comment: I would not see "Bist du kalt?" as a "normal" (or "valid", as you say) expression in German. Yes, gramatically it is alright. And, yes, you can find some veeery special situations where you could use "Bist du kalt?", but mostly they are deliberately constructed peculiar situations just to justify the odd expression, nothing that would happen in real life. Yes, you can grab somebody's hand and say "Oh, du bist aber kalt". But you would never ask "Bist du kalt?". You may ask: "Hast du kalte Füße?".

Answer (score 0):

The difference between *Ich bin krank* and *Mir ist kalt* ist the subject of the sentence.

First, let's have a look at the following sentences:

> - *Ich* bin krank.
>     
>   <sup>(*I* am sick.)</sup>
> - *Es* ist kalt.
>     
>   <sup>(*It* is cold.)</sup>

Here, the subjects are *ich* and *it*, respectively. If you want to say that it is *me* who feels the coldness of the abstract subject *it*, you can add the dative object *mir*:

> - *Es* ist *mir* kalt.
>     
>   or
> - *Mir* ist *es* kalt.

Both sentences might sound a bit strange to a native speaker, but they are correct. In fact, when the verb is a form of *sein*, then the abstract subject *es* is often omitted, i.e., it is present only implicitly:

> - *Mir* ist kalt.

The sentence

> *Ich* bin kalt.

is also possible but means that *I* am the subject being cold (my body). Often the expression *jemand ist kalt* is used as a metaphor to say that someone is coldhearted (see meaning 3. of [*kalt*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kalt)).

Finally, have a look at

> *Er* scheint *mir* krank.
>   
> <sup>(*He* appears sick *to me*.)</sup>

Here, *er* is the subject being sick, and *mir* is the dative object to whom his being sickness appears. The sentence

> *Mir* ist krank.

does not make sense, for it means that there is an abstract *it* being sick, and *I* only feel its sickness.