# Was heißt "Ist mir zu warm?" auf Englisch?

Tags: translation, meaning, idiom

> Ist mir zu warm?

Ich weiß alle der Wörter im Satz, aber ich verstehe die Bedeutung nicht.

The reason I ask is because I’m unsure exactly how/why the dative case *mir* shows up. What could be done to/for *me* to make it dative?

I guess it is asking “Am I too warm?”, but I’m just trying to understand grammatically how and why the dative shows up. If I were to translate “Am I too warm?”, I would probably arrive at “Bin ich zu warm?”, and not what is written above.

Comment: Related (could even be considered a duplicate): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/is-mir-ist-kalt-correct-did-i-hear-it-correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reflexive pronoun appearing here is indeed a typical feature of German. Let me start with a similar sentence, where I am more confident that I get the English right:

> I am cold.

This means that I am feeling cold. However the direct German translation does not express the same thing.

> Ich bin kalt.

This would either be a curious detached statement of the fact that my body temperature is low, without any hint of me actually feeling that, or the statement that I am a cold person. To express that I am feeling cold, I would say

> Mir ist kalt.

Equivalently, but in a slightly roundabout way, I could say

> Es ist mir kalt.

You recognised correctly that a direct translation would be “It is cold to me”, which is of course ungrammatical in English.

Now it is easy to understand

> Ist mir zu warm?

which is however a somewhat strange question, because it means

> Am I feeling too warm?

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense after your comparison to "ich bin kalt". Thank you!

I should have made that connection, because I know the same thing applies to moods (you wouldn't say ich bin schelcht for the same reason). 

Could warm in this context mean anything other than temperature? (ie, warm-hearted)

Comment: Exactly, “ich bin schlecht” would be funny. And “mir ist warm” really means that I am feeling warm, by itself I can only imagine it being related to the temperature. You could say “mir ist warm ums Herz” to express that you are feeling a warmth in your (figurative) heart. On the other hand “ich bin warm” could maybe with the proper context mean that you are a warm-hearted or affectionate person.

Comment: "Mir ist heiß" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzC52ohz3ts

Comment: @JanDoggen, „ich schwitze in der Ritze“. Nicht der Gipfel deutscher Dichtkunst, aber darauf kam es damals nicht an. Die ersten beiden Alben waren super.