# Does position of nicht matter?

Tags: word-order, negation

Suppose I want to say "I am not cold". I know this is "Ich bin nicht kalt". Is "Ich bin kalt nicht" also valid or is it incorrect?

I ask because I often see "nicht" at the end of the sentence, but other times I see it before the adjective/verb/noun.

Comment: Not important for your question but please note: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/is-mir-ist-kalt-correct-did-i-hear-it-correctly

Comment: I'm confused here. I'd say it should always say "Ich _habe_ (nicht) kalt". "Kalt sein" usually means to be either without conscience or just dead.

Comment: @CarstenS Oh, well there is a whole other can of worms. For the purposes of this question then perhaps replace "kalt" with "müde". I know nicht normally precedes adjectives and follows verbs but I am curious if "ich bin müde nicht" is considered to be incorrect German or if it just (say) has a different connotation.

Comment: @bwv869, I agree, changing that would be a good idea.

Comment: @PMF, „habe kalt” muss dann wohl regional sein, denn für mich klingt das schlicht falsch.

Comment: @CarstenS: Oder vielleicht eine 1:1 Übersetzung aus dem Französischen (J'ai froid.)? Wie dem auch sei, mir ist das im Deutschen bislang auch noch nie begegnet...

Comment: @PMF »Ich bin kalt« kann aber auch bedeuten, dass ich schlicht keine Gefühlsregung zeige. Also wie manche Mafiabosse/Bösewichte in Filmen dargestellt werden.

Answer (score 4):

*Nicht* generally precedes the item to negate.

> **Mir ist** nicht kalt.

*I am not cold.*

> Ich bin nicht müde.

*I am not sleepy.*

There is an alternative function of *nicht* however: as an interjection.

> Sie haben es verstanden, nicht?

*You have understood, haven't you?*

It's not so common in Northern Germany but I hear it very often from Swiss German speakers. *Oder* is a replacement which is very common.

Maybe that's the *nicht* you hear ever so often?

And finally there's

> Das finde ich nicht.

*I don't think so.*

> Ich glaube dir nicht.

*I don't believe you.*

> Sie gab ihm ihre Telefonnummer nicht.

*She didn't give him her phone number.*

which negates the whole sentence. English uses *do not* for the same purpose.

Comment: So the difference is what type of word you are negating. For an adverb it is in front, for verbs it is after? Could you outline this a bit more?

Comment: Where do you see the nicht *after* a verb? No. For negating a whole clause it isn't after a verb but at the end of the clause. If there are parts of the finite verb which are placed at the end of the same non-negated clause, they still come after the *nicht*. And for non-finite verbs, *nicht* is also front of them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the position matters.

There a two meanings of **I'm not cold**:

> Ich bin nicht kalt - my body temperature isn't below 36 degrees Celsius.
>   Mir ist nicht kalt - the surrounding temperature is high enough.

---

**The positioning:**

---

1. Negation of the whole sentence:
   *nicht* is positioned at the **end of the clause** if there is **no adverb, prepositional object or part of the predicate**:

> Ich schlafe **nicht**.
>   Ich liebe dich (accusative object) **nicht**.
>   Ich gebe dir (dative object) das Buch (accusative object) **nicht**.

But:

> Ich fahre nicht **schnell**.
>   Ich bringe dich nicht **in die Schule**.
>   Ich **trinke** das Glas nicht **aus**.
>   Ich **habe** darüber nicht **gelacht**.
>   Ich **möchte** heute nicht **fernsehen**.
>   Das **will** ich nicht **gehört haben**.

---

2. Negation of one part of the clause: nicht is positioned in front of this part, that will automatically be stressed. A 'but' is pending:

Positive:

> Ich fahre oft mit dem Auto zur Arbeit.

Negated:

> **Nicht ich** fahre oft mit dem Auto zur Arbeit. (*Sondern* eine andere Person)
>   Ich fahre **nicht oft** mit dem Auto zur Arbeit. (*aber* manchmal)
>   Ich fahre oft **nicht mit dem Auto** zur Arbeit. (*sondern* mit dem Bus oder Rad)
>   Ich fahre mit dem Auto oft **nicht zur Arbeit**. (*sondern* zum Einkaufen)

Since *zur Arbeit* is stressed in this last example, *oft* has to change position, too.

---

3. **..., nicht?** as abbreviated (rhetorical) request to confirm or to agree:

> Das Wetter ist schön, **nicht** (wahr)? *The weather is nice, isn't it.*

Comment: *I am cold* (or: *Ich bin kalt)* can also refer to emotional coldness; i.e. *I am not cold* could mean *I am able to smile/laugh* etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nicht negates the word that it precedes. That's except when it comes at the end of a sentence or a clause, in which case, it negates the whole clause. So yes, the position does matter.

To take one of the other examples,

Ich bin nicht müde. I am not *tired.* I may be happy, or alert, or even annoyed but the one thing is I'm not is "tired."

Ich bin müde nicht. I am tired, not. (This is more of a British construction than an American construction.)

You may be tired, or s/he may be tired, but I am not the one that is "tired."