# When does "nicht" stand before and when after a direct object expressed by a noun?

Tags: noun, negation, objects

I understand that objects expressed by pronouns usually go in front of "nicht" and objects expressed by a noun or a pronoun with a preposition usually go after "nicht", but what should I do with direct objects expressed by nouns?

I've heard that it can depend on whether the whole sentence or part of the sentence is being negated, but although that's clear with textbook examples, it gets more complicated in real-life situations.  For example, here are some examples of negative sentences with direct objects expressed by nouns, some of which have "nicht" before the noun, and some after.

#### Before:

> - Im Sommer kann sie **nicht ihr langes Programm** machen.
> - Er konnte **nicht dem Druck** überwinden, dem die Föderation ihn unterwarf.
> - Ich verstand **nicht den Großteil ihres Gespräches**.
> - Es gefällt mir auch nicht, dass Frodo **nicht den Ring** ins Feuer werfen konnte.

#### After:

> - Er hat **das Verspechen** noch **nicht** erfüllt.
> - Nun hatte ich **den Erzähler nicht** gern.
> - Ich muß eingestehen, dass ich **Sofie nicht** bedauere, weil ich **die Leute nicht** bedauern kann, die sich nicht bedauern.
> - Andererseits bedaure ich Isabel, obwohl ich **viel Geld** oder **einen hohen Stellenwert nicht** brauche, aber sie brauchte es und ich bedaure sie, dass sie **jene** und **ihre Liebe** auch **nicht** haben konnte.
> - Ich denke, dass sie **das Buch von Le Guin nicht** gelesen haben mag.
> - Ich werde **diese letzte Stunde nicht** besuchen können.

I understand that it's not an easy question even for native speakers to answer, since it's not something they learn consciously, but if somebody happened to know why "nicht" is placed where it is in these examples and could explain it to me, so that I'd know how to place it in the future, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: It's **never** after some object, it's always **before** some part of the sentence. See e.g. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/negating-verbs-and-nouns/36769#36769

Comment: In German grammar there is nothing like *direct* or *indirect objects*. We have dative objects, accusative objects, genitive objects, prepositional objects and under certain circumstances even nominative objects. But if you look into any German grammar book, you never will find the terms *direct object* or *indirect object*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Any English or French speaker who studied basic grammar is familiar with the terms *direct* and *indirect* object. These are concepts they can apply to the German language. They only need to learn that a direct object takes the accusative and an indirect the dative. The fact that Germans don't use these terms is irrelevant for them.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast And I'm sorry: I meant German *speakers* and not Germans

Comment: Thank you for responding. I had tried to find an answer to this question both on this forum and on the Internet in general before posting here. I've had various questions regarding German grammar as I was learning the language, and usually I could find the answer already there.  However, in this case, although it's clear to me in case of simple textbook-like phrases, it's not so clear-cut in real-life more complex phrases.

Comment: In particular, I don't see why "nicht" should stand before accusative or dative objects in the first four examples, but not in the following ones - or rather why it should be before these objects in the first examples, as the latter approach sounds more natural to me, but then what do I know - I'm only learning the language.

Comment: Well, in the third example this placing makes sense: I couldn't understand most of the conversation, but I could understand something. And it does sound more natural that way.  But in the other three examples in the first group the whole phrase is being negated, as far as I can see, just like in the second group of sentences. Actually, in the last example in the second group, I meant, I won't be able to attend the last class, but I will come to the others. I would be very grateful if somebody could help me understand this matter

Comment: As I've already explained twice, understanding it with simple phrases and with more complex real-life examples is not the same thing, IMO, just like a math textbook which explains that 2+2 is 4 is not the same as the textbook which explains how to add multiple-digit numbers. In any case, I'm very glad that my question was answered.  I've found the answers very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases you can simply change the position of the "*nicht*" and the meaning of the sentence is still the same.

However the difference *seems* (I'm not absolutely sure) to be that you deny the word which is following the word "*nicht*":

> Im Sommer kann sie **nicht ihr langes Programm** machen.

... however she can do something different.

> Sie kann ihr langes Programm **nicht im Sommer** machen.

... however she can do it in other times of the year.

> Im Sommer macht **nicht sie** ihr langes Programm.

... however someone different does it.

Denying the verb is a bit more complex: if a sentence does not contain an infinitive nor an auxiliary verb you put the "*nicht*" at the end of the sentence; otherwise you put it in front of the infinitive or participle:

> Sie **macht** das Programm **nicht**.
>
> Sie **hat** das Programm **nicht gemacht**.
>
> Sie **will** das Programm **nicht machen**.

(Note: For "separable verbs" like "einkaufen" it is a bit more complex.)

To deny the entire sentence you typically deny the verb.

**At least for all of your examples** this works. In all these examples you could move the word "*nicht*" into another position to deny another part of the sentence.

However the following example is interesting:

> ... dass Frodo den Ring **ins** Feuer **nicht werfen** konnte. (*Wrong?*)

It seems to sound very strange when denying the (non-separable) verb in a sentence containing a preposition (here "*ins*"). Therefore the translator of the story denied the word "ring" to deny the entire sentence and not the verb.

I myself however would have denied the part "into the fire" to deny the entire sentence:

> ... dass Frodo den Ring **nicht ins Feuer** werfen konnte.

So you have a perfect example where two different native speakers would put the word "*nicht*" in a different position.

---

By the way:

> Er konnte nicht **dem** Druck überwinden, **dem** die Föderation ihn unterwarf.

I'm not absolutely sure but I think that the first "*dem*" should be "*den*" because the verb "*überwinden*" is formed with an accussative. The second "*dem*" however seems to be correct: It is used with the verb "unterwerfen" which is requires a dative here:

> Er konnte nicht **de*n*** Druck überwinden, **de*m*** die Föderation ihn unterwarf.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That's really helpful.  I think I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

German allows much more freedom in the word order than English. Still, there is often a more commonly used word order, and changes from that can be used to convey (sometimes only nuanced) emphases.

Regarding the *Before* and *After* examples in the question, the *After* form is the more common one. To my native ears, all of the *Before* examples would also sound slightly more natural if they were changed to the *After* form, i.e., placing the *nicht* before the verb at the end of the clause or, in absence of an verb at the end, right at the end of the clause. As such, the *nicht* modifies not the object, but the predicate of the sentence:

> - Im Sommer konnte sie ihr langes Programm **nicht machen**.
> - Er konnte den Druck **nicht überwinden**, dem die Förderation ihn unterwarf.
> - Ich **verstand** den Großteil ihres Gespräches **nicht**.
> - Es gefällt mir auch nicht, dass Frodo den Ring **nicht ins Feuer werfen konnte**.

The *Before* form suggests an emphasis to the part of the sentence following the *nicht*. E.g.,

> - Im Sommer konnte sie **nicht ihr langes Programm** machen. Sie musste sich auf **das kurze Programm** beschränken.
> - Er konnte **nicht den Druck** überwinden, dem die Föderation ihn unterwarf. **Die moralische Fragwürdigkeit seiner geplanten Handlung** hätte ihn hingegen nicht aufgehalten.
> - Ich verstand **nicht den Großteil ihres Gesprächs**. Aber ich verstand sehr wohl, **dass sie wütend über ihre Situation waren**.
> - Es gefällt mir auch nicht, dass Frodo **nicht den Ring** ins Feuer werfen konnte. Er konnte ja **alle möglichen anderen Dinge** ins Feuer werfen.

Comment: Can the downvote please be explained?

Comment: I'm also confused why somebody voted it down.  Personally I've found your reply very helpful.  Thank you very much!