# Is the position of "nicht" in the past tense (preterite/imperfect) the same as the position of "nicht" in the present tense?

Tags: negation

I'd just like to know, I have just finished learning the position of "nicht" in the present tense, but is the position of "nicht" in the past tense as same as in the present tense?

Examples:

> Ich ging nicht nach Hause. <=> Ich gehe nicht nach Hause.
>   Ich arbeitete gestern nicht. <=> Ich arbeite heute nicht.
>   Ich kochte nicht gern. <=> Ich koche nicht gern.
>   Das Flugzeug flog nicht ab. <=> Das Flugzeug fliegt nicht ab.

Comment: What do you call "the same position"? Can you give examples of the same and not the same positions please.

Comment: We could give examples, but you want to know something, and so it's your job to give examples. What do you think is correct? Where exactly are you unsure?

Comment: This question seems to assume that *nicht* has a certain fixed (or "correct") position in sentences. It hasn't - That position can vary according to what exactly should be negated. ("Ich arbeitete gestern nicht" vs. "Ich arbeitete nicht gestern" vs. "Nicht ich arbeitete gestern(. Sondern x)") - All correct positions.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome on this site.

Last week there were two questions ([this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/where-is-exactly-the-position-of-nicht-in-the-sentence) and [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/when-does-nicht-stand-before-and-when-after-a-direct-object-expressed-by-a-nou/40699?noredirect=1)) about the position of the word "*nicht*" on this site:

It's much more complex than you think...

However:

The position in the two tenses not using an auxiliary verb (present and imperfect) is the same, unless a verb is used with an infinitive (e.g. "*wollen*" - "*to want to*").

So the answer to your question is: Yes, the positions are the same.

In the tenses using an auxiliary verb (future, perfect, ...) the position of the word "*nicht*" is also the same - however it is different from the tenses without auxiliary verb.

So when asking for the position of the "*nicht*" the question is: Is this tense using an auxiliary verb or not?

(Present and imperfect both do not use an auxiliary verb so the position of the "*nicht*" is the same.)

Comment: an auxiliary verb is not always present.

Comment: @AqshaIsham I edited the last part of my answer.

Comment: The term *preterite* should be preferred over *imperfect* because that tense in German is simply used for the past and not for actions which are still ongoing, as in languages with a true imperfect (like Latin or romance languages).